# Laravel8 sendmail driver not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, sendmail, laravel-mail

I would like to ask if my .env and mail.php is correct. I already checked all the questions related in here but so far all of them lead me to the same error. Below is the error message

> Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path
> specified. ] {"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code:
> 0): Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path
> specified. ] at
> C:\xampp4\htdocs\payroll\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php:294)

Here is my .env file

```
MAIL_MAILER=sendmail
MAIL_SENDMAIL='/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i'
```

And this is my mail.php

```
<?php

return [
    'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),
    'sendmail' => env('MAIL_SENDMAIL', '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs'),

    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 2525),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],

        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],

        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => env('MAIL_SENDMAIL', '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs'),
        ],

        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],

        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],
    ],

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],


    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

Comment: I think `'sendmail' => env('MAIL_SENDMAIL', '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs')` should be there :  `'mailers' => 'sendmail' => 'path' => env('MAIL_SENDMAIL', '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs'),`

Comment: Hi @ClémentBaconnier, I already inserted your suggestion, but the error is still persisting, I already edited the file above

Comment: Does sendmail is actually installed and can be found at this path?

Comment: Honestly, I didn't install anything, can you give me some link on how to do it? sorry for the inconvenience, still a newbie in laravel mail functionality

Comment: you will have issues with sendmail if you are not familiar with mail systems.  (EG) it will get flagged as spam and or not deliver if you don't set it up properly.  I suggest using a service like mailgun or sendgrid

Comment: thank you very much @Cameron, I will use this service instead